# Google- map restrictions not working?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to validate an input address using the Google Maps API and plain Javascript. My idea was to find the latitudes and longitudes for the input address, and then restrict it to a specific country (in my case, France). Otherwise, show an error.

I have the following code:

```
function validateInputMeans() {
    var address = prompt("Please Enter Address");
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'FR' }
    };
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status,options) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            alert("Address Entered is valid French Address.");
        }
        else{
            alert("Invalid Address. Please Try-Again.");
        }
    });
}
```

My code is working, but if I enter an address which is outside of France, it still shows me a valid French address.

For example, if I enter `26 Leicester Square, London`, it still shows me a valid French address. This is my first time working with the Google Maps API, and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The restrictions need to be part of your request to the `geocode` function.  Not an optional argument in the callback function.

Change:

```
var options = {
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'FR' }
};
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status,options) {
```

To:

```
var options = {
    address: address,
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'FR' }
};
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode(options, function (results, status) {
```